# Object lifetime of std::stirng returning const char* as a return value

Tags: c++11

In C++11:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const char*Inner() {
  std::string content;
  content = "const characters are returned.";
  return content.c_str();
}

const char* Outer() {
  return Inner();
}
int main(){
  std::cout << "result " << Outer() <<"\n"; // <- Spot 1
  return 0;
}
```

I am kind of understand the explanation in [const char* Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056916/const-char-return-type). The string object is destroyed when the stack is gone. But I think that should happen when the `Spot 1` completed execution. After that, the `Inner` stack is popped? But in this case, the `Spot 1` is still executing but the stacks are destroyed. Could anyone explain when the stack gets destroyed?

Another question related the context is： if I change the function to

```
const char*Inner() {
  std::string content;
  content = "const characters are returned.";
  const char* ptr = content.c_str()
  return ptr;
}
```

In this case, The string content is destroyed. Is that because the return is a pointer, so the value of the pointer(address) is returned but the content the pointer pointed to is recycled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` destructs when `Inner` exits, right after returning the pointer.  The pointer returned by `Inner` is therefore a dangling pointer from the moment it's returned.

The same is true for the second version of `Inner` you've written here.  `content` goes out of scope at the end of `Inner`, and `Inner` returns a dangling pointer.

So the pointer is invalid long before the `cout` statement finishes executing.

The function `Outer` here is basically irrelevant.

That said, if you run this program, you may still print out the expected value in the `cout` statement, because the memory that the dangling pointer points to might still contain the value it contained before.  But there's no guarantee of this, and the optimizer in particular may realize that there's no way the value of `content` can legitimately affect anything and respond by never initializing it in the first place.